# Priority queue (from scratch) and linked lists

Tags: java, linked-list, priority-queue

I am trying to create a linked list from some unordered raw data (String1...Priority10, String2...IntPriority2, etc) and have had trouble conceptualizing how I can sort write a good method for priority queueing. I need to get the method to enqueue each object, in order, without using a sorting algorithm on the final linked list, or using any LinkedList or PriorityQueue itself.

My enqueue method, nothing hard here:

```
    public class ObjectQueue{
Object front = null;           //points to first element of the queue
Object prev = null;            //points to last element of the queue 
  /**
 * Creates an object of Object and adds to the class queue
 * @param name of object
 * @param rank of priority sort
 */
public void enQueue(String name, int rank)
{
    Object current = new Object(name, rank);  //uses current entry String as name, int as rank

    if(isEmpty())               //if empty, add element to front
    {
        front = current;
    }
    else                        //if elements exist, go to end and create new element
    {
        prev.next = current;
    }
    prev = current;
```

And the priority sort and add method I'm having trouble with:

```
/**
 * Adds each object and rank on a ascending rank basis
 * @param filename name of data file
 * @throws exc in case of missing file
 */
public void addPriority(String filename) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
    File inFile = new File(filename);           //inst. file import
    Scanner read = new Scanner(inFile);         //inst. scanner object

    String name1 = read.next();              //scanner reads next string, primes at front
    int rank1 = read.nextInt();              //reads next int, assigns to rank

    while (read.hasNext())                      //reads until end of text
    {
        String name2 = read.next();              //next string of next Object to be tested
        int rank2 = read.nextInt();              //rank to test rank1 against

        if (rank1 > rank2)                      //if current is higher priority than test
        {
            enQueue(name1, rank1);              //enqueue the current object
            name1 = name2;                      //move test name down to current
            rank1 = rank2;                      //move test rank down to current
        }
        else
        {
            enQueue(name2, rank2);              //enqueue the current object
        }
    }
    read.close();                               //ends read when empty

    }
    catch(Exception exec)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: file not found.");
    }

}
```

I need to get this one single method to either pre-sort the objects without sending them to a list, or sorting them properly, one time, while on-the-fly, and I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: You don't need to sort to implement a priority queue. You should read about heaps. Also why are you using a linked list and not an array? This is very inefficient approach

Comment: I'm required to use a linked list for this, rather than an array. And no LinkedList objects, just my own from scratch.

Comment: Then read about binary heaps and try to implement them using a *doubly* linked list (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29)

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually (ignoring implementation) a priority queue is pretty simple. It needs to be able to add an item with a priority and it needs to be able to get the item with the highest (or, in some implementations, lowest) priority. An additional constraint that is sometimes included is that for two items with equal priority the item added first must be retrieved first.

So that's the concept. For us to help you might need to provide some more details on exactly how your priority queue is supposed to work. For the following notes I'll assume:
- retrieve highest priority first
- equal priority should be retrieved in insertion order

Looking at implementation, the underlying structure could be just about any collection as long as insertion is allowed and insertion order is preserved. The traditional implementation is a heap because they use memory efficiently and are very fast but a linked list (single or double) is fine functionally.

Clearly priority queues imply an order of retrieval. This can be implemented at insertion or retrieval time. Again this decision will be dictated by usage and again it seems your implementation can ignore these factors.

So my suggestion would be, to keep it simple, that you sort at insertion time rather than at retrieval time. Without supplying you actual code (which I'm assuming is your task) here's a basic algorithm that could implement an insertion time priority queue.

```
class PriorityItem {
    private final Item item;
    private final int priority;
}

Collection<PriorityItem> queue;

void insert(Item item, int priority) {
    PriorityItem element = new PriorityItem(item, priority); 
    if queue is not empty {
        step through queue {
            if current.priority < priority {
                insert element here
                return
            }
        }
    }
    add element to end queue
}
```

Then retrieval is trivial: it's just the first item in the queue.